# Neo4j Cypher Shortest path with properties

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I've successfully run a shortest-path algorithm using CYPHER client (C#) below.

However, I'm struggling to return all the properties for the nodes and relationships as another application adds other properties and I want to avoid creating an entirely new class for the results; making it dynamic.

The other application reads an XML file where tags other can be added, it creates a dynamicObject when parsing the XML and uploads it into the graph database. For example, someone may add Speed to the Road element or population count for a Town.

I've tried reflection to get all the Properties under the nodes and node.Data, but it is not listing any. If I create a class, then it does get the values but rather it be more dynamic.

Any ideas? Thanks.

The code below gets all the nodes and edges but not their properties. If I replace "RelationshipInstance" with a class with Road, it then gets the Length but not any others that may be there.

```
var query = graphClient.Cypher
    .Match($"p=(c:Location {{ Name: \"{start}\"}})-[:Road*..10]->(b:Location {{ Name: \"{end}\"}})")
    .Return((p) => new
    {
        Nodes = Return.As<IEnumerable<Node<object>>>("nodes(p)"),
        Relationships = Return.As<IEnumerable<RelationshipInstance<object>>>("rels(p)"),
        Distance = Return.As<double>("reduce(km = 0, r in relationships(p) | km + r.Length)")

    })
    .OrderBy("Distance ASC")
    .Limit(1).Results;

public class Location {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public long Population {get;set;}

}

public class Town : Location {
    public long PropA {get;set;}

}

public class City : Location {
    public string PropA {get;set;}
    public long PropB {get;set;}

}

public class Road {
    public double Length {get;set;}

}
```

Comment: what you mean by " as another application adds other properties" ? What above code does ? Does it work ? Why reflection does not help ? Show error ? Maybe you can try JSON stringfy things like that

Comment: I've added some text to the first post.

Reflection doesn't let me access any of the properties, it doesn't even show any. No error.